# Password not checking length condition in Java

Tags: java, validation, passwords, runtime-error, conditional-statements

I have been struggling around for 4 hours but the string in which I am taking my password is not checking the length condition. I know i am doing some stupid mistake but unfortunately I can't figure it out. Finally I decided to ask from Experts here kindly help me with this.

PS: I am writing a function to validate the password to be 4 to 11 characters long,contain one uppercase character,one lowercase character,one digit and one special character.

```
public void validPassword(){
    String password;
    boolean con = true;

    Pattern[] passRegex = new Pattern[4];

    {
        passRegex[0] = Pattern.compile(".*[A-Z].*");
        passRegex[1] = Pattern.compile(".*[a-z].*");
        passRegex[2] = Pattern.compile(".*\\d.*");
        passRegex[3] = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]*");
    }

    while(con){
        System.out.println("Enter Your Password Using Correct Format:");
        password = input.next();

            if(password.length() < 4 && password.length() > 11){
                System.out.println("Your Password Should Be 4 To 11 Characters Long");
            }
            if(!passRegex[0].matcher(password).matches()){
                System.out.println("Your Password Must Contain Atleast One UpperCase Letter");
                }
            if(!passRegex[1].matcher(password).matches()){
                System.out.println("Your Password Must Contain Atleast One LowerCase Letter");
                }
            if(!passRegex[2].matcher(password).matches()){
                System.out.println("Your Password Must Contain Atleast One Digit");
                }
            if(passRegex[3].matcher(password).matches()){
                System.out.println("Your Password Must Contain Atleast One Special Character");
                }
            else{
            System.out.println("Your Password Is Correct");
            con = false;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need or in your first condition not and

```
        if(password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 11){
```

not

```
        if(password.length() < 4 && password.length() > 11){
```

Comment: OMG ! See I told you there is a stupid mistake i am making. Actually I am exhausted after four hours of coding.
Thanks a lot for the Help.